# Pipe that maintains state

Tags: haskell, haskell-pipes

I'm trying to calculate rolling hash values (buzzhash) for a big file using `pipes`.

Currently I have this. But don't know how to write a pipe that maintains a state.

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as L
import Data.Word
import Data.Bits(xor,rotate)
import Data.Array
import Pipes
import Control.Monad.State.Strict
import Control.Monad(forever)

produceFromList (x:xs) = do 
  yield x
  produceFromList xs

buzzHash = do
  x <- await
  h <- lift $ get -- pull out previous value
  let h' = rotate h 1 `xor` (hashArrW8!x) -- calculate new value
  lift $ put h' -- save new value 
  yield h'

stdoutLn :: Consumer Word64 IO ()
stdoutLn = do 
  a <- await 
  lift $ print a

main = do 
  bs <- L.unpack `fmap` L.getContents
  runEffect $ produceFromList bs >-> buzzHash >-> stdoutLn

hashArrW8 :: Array Word8 Word64
```

How do I make buzzHash save previous value and use it for the calculation of next value? Initial state value should be 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there; you just need to run the state.

```
main = do
  bs <- L.unpack `fmap` L.getContents
  flip execStateT 0 $ runEffect $ produceList bs >-> buzzHash >-> hoist lift stdoutLn
```

I assume you don't want to recover the state, so I use `execStateT` rather than `runStateT`.

The only curiosity here is that `stdoutLn` was marked as `Consumer Word64 IO ()` . So I use `hoist lift` to make it `Consumer Word64 (StateT Word64 IO) ()` Everything in the series `a >-> b >-> c` must agree in the underlying monad and return type.

Here are a few further comments that might save you time. First `produceFromList` is `each`.

Moreover, you could have avoided the `hoist lift` by relabeling your `stdoutLn`:

```
stdoutLn :: MonadIO m => Consumer Word64 m ()
stdoutLn = do 
   a <- await 
   liftIO $ print a
```

But here there is some trouble: you are not repeating the action. This should pretty clearly be a loop:

```
stdoutLn :: MonadIO m => Consumer Word64 m ()
stdoutLn = do 
   a <- await 
   liftIO $ print a
   stdoutLn
```

in fact this is already available as `P.print`, so we can write

```
import qualified Pipes.Prelude as P
main = do
  bs <- L.unpack `fmap` L.getContents
  flip execStateT 0 $ runEffect $ each bs >-> buzzHash >-> P.print
```

If I understand you, `buzzHash` is meant to be repeated indefinitely too:

```
buzzHash = do
  x <- await
  h <- lift $ get -- pull out previous value
  let h' = rotate h 1 `xor` (hashArrW8!x) -- calculate new value
  lift $ put h' -- save new value 
  yield h'
  buzzHash
```

(this is `forever buzzHash`, where we use your `buzzHash`)

Finally, if you

```
 import qualified Pipes.ByteString as PB
 import Control.Lens (view) -- (or Lens.Micro.MTL or Lens.Simple)
```

we see we don't need the lazy bytestring IO, which doesn't stream properly anyway.
`Pipes.ByteString` already has the `unpack` we want, packaged as a lens, so that we use `view PB.unpack` where elsewhere we would use `B.unpack`. So in the end we can write

```
main = flip evalStateT 0 $ runEffect $ view PB.unpack PB.stdin >-> buzzHash >-> P.print
```

Once it is in this form we see we aren't using the underlying state of the pipeline except in `buzzHash`, so we can localize this

```
import Pipes.Lift (evalStateP) 
main =  runEffect $ view PB.unpack PB.stdin >-> evalStateP 0 buzzHash >-> P.print
```

or, if you like you can rewrite

```
buzzHash' :: Monad m => Word64 -> Pipe Word8 Word64 m r
buzzHash' n = evalStateP n $ forever $ do
    x <- await
    h <- lift $ get -- pull out previous value
    let h' = rotate h 1 `xor` (hashArrW8!x) -- calculate new value
    lift $ put h' -- save new value 
    yield h'
```

Then you would write

```
main =  runEffect $ view PB.unpack PB.stdin >-> buzzHash' 0 >-> P.print
```

Comment: is everything after `buzzHash` in a state monad?

Comment: The three pipe things linked by `>->` all transform `(StateT Word64 IO)`, yes. So, `buzzHash` is specialized to `Pipe Word8 Word64 (StateT Word64 IO) ()`, `P.print` specializes to `Consumer Word64 (StateT Word64 IO) ()`, and `view PB.unpack PB.stdin` to `Producer Word8 (StateT Word64 IO) ()` to use the type-synonyms pipes uses. So when you glue them together side by side, you get an `Effect (StateT Word64 IO) ()`. So then when you apply `runEffect` you get a `StateT Word64 IO ()`. And next when you apply `runStateT` you have a `Word64 -> IO ((),Word64)`.

Comment: I added a bit about `evalStateP` etc. at the end. Maybe this is more suitable, since it doesn't involve tuning the pipeline so that everything agrees. Rather, we just write a `buzzHash` function that doesn't explicitly involve `StateT` in the type.